# Remove LibGDX logs in Android using ProGuard

Tags: android, logging, ant, libgdx, proguard

I have a `proguard.cfg` file which contains several statements including optimization passes and logs suppression as :

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }

-assumenosideeffects class com.badlogic.gdx.Application {
    public static void debug(...);
    public static void error(...);
    public static void log(...);
}
```

Calls to `Log.*` are correctly removed in the final output APK file. But gdx log calls are still in the code. For example I can still see things like that in the output :

```
Gdx.app.debug("debug()", "^");
Gdx.app.error("error()", "^");
Gdx.app.log("log()", "^");
```

I also tried to put this part of my config in a `proguard-optimize.txt` file as I have seen on similar questions and then setting the proper value in `project.properties` files like this : `proguard.config=proguard-optimize.txt:proguard.txt` but **it doesn't work** !

These calls get removed **only** if I put a general wildcard :

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.badlogic.gdx.Application {
    *;
}
```

But I don't want to remove calls to other `Application`'s static methods, like `add*` and `get*()` ones.

Optimization step is enabled (6 passes).

Comment: I don't know much about proguard, but could it be a problem that the calls are actually using an `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication` instance?  (`Application` is an interface.)

Comment: Indeed it could be the case, but then I don't understand why the calls get removed when I use a wildcard. I'll try anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Gdx.app.debug` is not `static`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.java#L141) its an instance method (`app` is a static field of the `Gdx` class).

Try:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.badlogic.gdx.Application {
    public void debug(...);
    public void error(...);
    public void log(...);
}
```

Comment: Indeed you are right. I should probably code less and sleep more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your application's code:

```
Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_NONE);
```

That will prevent messages from being logged.

Cheers!

Comment: Log messages will not be in the output in console but log statements will still be present in the source code. You're not answering the question. Thanks anyway.